# Youtube iframe responsive and float left

Tags: css, iframe, youtube

I need to make a youtube iframe responsive and also that the iframe is left floating to add content to the right, I tried with this code but the iframe is not responsive?

Thanks.

The JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/94150148/vh04d7y2/

```css
.videoWrapper {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 51.44%; /* 16:9 */
 padding-top: 25px;
 height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.box1 {
       float:left;
       width: 400px
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
<div class="videoWrapper">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6apL89xgbR0"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div>
<div class="box2">Some text</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest to use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for making embedded videos responsive which are added through iframe, following is the code which you can use to make the iframe responsive

```
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>

<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

But make sure to add bootstrap.css and and other bootstrap dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

All you need is max-width:

```
.left {max-width: 400px;}
```